# Issues with executing a query that calculates the sum of recent rows and inserts results in a new column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am very new to PHP and MySQL so sorry in advance.  I am trying to execute a query that computes the sum of the most recent 30 rows of a column and insert the results into a different column in the table.

Here is the code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);

$sql1 = ("SELECT sum(open) FROM (SELECT date,open FROM AA ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30) sumopen30");
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql1);

$resultarray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$attempts = $resultarray["open"];

echo $attempts;

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO AA (sum) VALUES ('$attempts')";
mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
```

I am not getting any results, updates, or errors.  If I change the query to "SELECT open FROM AA WHERE open > 40" the data is echoed but the so I am thinking there is an issue with the query.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You may be ne to MySQL but at least you're using mysqli. That puts you ahead of *a lot* of people. +1

Comment: Why are you using subqueries to sum? this could be done in a simple query

Comment: If you are not doing any calculation in php, you can insert directly in your first SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, the sum isn't stored in open - the field is named `sum(open)`

You can also simplify the query and give the sum(open) a new name

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);

$sql1 = ("SELECT sum(open) as sum_open FROM AA ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30");
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql1);

$resultarray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$attempts = $resultarray["sum_open"];

echo $attempts;

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO AA (sum) VALUES ('$attempts')";
mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql1 = ("SELECT sum(open) as open FROM AA ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30");
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql1);

$resultarray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$attempts = $resultarray["open"];

echo $attempts;

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO AA (sum) VALUES ($attempts)";
mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
```

I assume you `num` field is numeric.